# How to Send a String via Bluetooth from another Activity

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

So this is my problem: I made an app in which I need to send a string via Bluetooth, the String is a collection of data from a spinner. 
The spinner is in the `MainActivity` where it populates with info from the database, and I got a simple BluetoothChat in another activity called `BtActivity`. 
What I'm trying to do is to make the info of the spinner (that I got in a String) to be sent via Bluetooth, but since it is in another activity I have no Idea how to do it. The ideal would be, if possible, that the string is sent from the `MainActivity`.

`MainActivity` important code:

```
buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            /*
            Collector of Pills
            */

            String shower = "";

            ArrayList<PillVO> list = PillVO.getPills(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

            for (PillVO p : list) {

                shower += p.getModulo() + ", " + p.getHorario() + "; ";

            }

/* This is the idea that I got for sending it

            BtActivity bta = new BtActivity();

            bta.SendMessageFromMain(shower);
*/
        }


    });

    loadSpinnerData();
} /// on create finishes
```

`BtActivity` important code:

```
    public void SendMessage() {
    byte[] bytes = text.toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
    Log.d(TAG, "SendMessage: "+ bytes);
    messages.setText(text.getText().toString());

    mConnectedThread.write(bytes);
}

/* Idea

public void SendMessageFromMain(String lolo) {
    byte[] bytes = lolo.toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
    Log.d(TAG, "SendMessage: "+ bytes);
    messages.setText(text.getText().toString());

    mConnectedThread.write(bytes);
}
*/
```

Comment: Simply send string from your MainActivity to BtActivity via intent

Comment: @UmerFarooq Would you mind to give me some Instructions please?

Answer (score 0):

Simply send string to `BtActivity` via intent.

In your `MainActivity`

```
buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            /*
            Collector of Pills
            */

            String shower = "";

            ArrayList<PillVO> list = PillVO.getPills(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

            for (PillVO p : list) {

                shower += p.getModulo() + ", " + p.getHorario() + "; ";

            }

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BtActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("shower", shower);
                    startActivity(intent);
        }


    });
```

In `BtActivity` you just get the string like

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("shower");

mConnectedThread.write(message.getBytes());
```